# How to not return lookup results in mongdb

Tags: mongodb

I would like to return accounts by checking if the account is used in any orders by using lookup feature. But i don't want to return lookup results. How can I ignore/remove/exclude the lookup results

```
Account.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                type: {$eq: type}
            },
        },
        {
            $lookup:
                {
                    from: "orders",
                    let: {accountId: {$toString : "$_id"}},
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match:
                                {
                                    $expr:
                                        {
                                            $and:
                                                [
                                                    {$eq: ["$$accountId", "$usedAccountId"]},
                                                    {$eq: ["$orderState","COMPLETED"]
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                    ],
                    as: "orders"
                }
        }
    ])
```

With above query, I get the following results. I want to get rid of orders array

```
[
 {
  //accountObject,
  orders: [
    //orderObject
 ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Probably there is no any other alternative, but you can check condition after lookup in `$match: { orders: { $ne: [] }`

Comment: What turivishal said, plus add `$limit: 1` to your pipeline to minimize drag out and throw away.

Comment: Have you tried `$project`?

Comment: $project works, I am kinda new to mongodb, just learned about it